# What OS X quicklook generator is used for java files?

Tags: macos, finder, quicklook

The OS X Finder previews selected documents using quicklook.

> [Q] How must my app be configured to be able intercept these requests and draw the preview?

Is there any way for my app to just forward the request of one file extension to another app that already handles a similar extension?

(This would be particularly useful for previewing my Ruby dsl using the existing ruby previewer. Or .scala files using the .java previewer built into XCode, for example.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`qlmanage -p -d1 somefile.java` gives:

```
Testing Quick Look preview with files:
    somefile.java

[DEBUG] Registering <QLGenerator Built-in 0x7fbf5b00b890> for public.image
[DEBUG] Preview test for somefile.java -- file://localhost/Users/XXX/. Content type UTI: com.sun.java-source
[DEBUG] Previewing file://localhost/Users/XXX/somefile.java. Content type UTI: com.sun.java-source. Generator used: <QLGenerator Text.qlgenerator>
[DEBUG] Loading <QLGenerator Text.qlgenerator>
[DEBUG] Previewing file://localhost/Users/XXX/somefile.java finished
```

Note that `com.sun.java-source` conforms to `public.source-code` which conforms to `public.plain-text`. Any type declared as conforming to `public.plain-text` will use the Text generator except if there is a more specific plugin.

The mapping file extension / content type is provided by applications (or Quick Look plugins). Look at [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319) for more info.

Notes:

- you can't change the list of types a generator supports without modifying the plug-in itself (which is a bad idea for a built-in system generator). The mapping type -> generator is built automatically based on what the generators declare in their Info.plist.
- if you want a type XXX to be handled by the Text generator, you have to declare XXX as conforming to `public.plain-text` in your application.
- if you don't want to formally declare that XXX conforms to `public.plain-text`, you'll have to write a generator yourself.

Comment: +1 for answering part (a). Do you have any idea how to assign a generator to all files of a given extension?

Comment: added some additional info. There is no central database you can modify to force a mapping, this mapping is based on declaration of what types conform to and what types each generator supports.

Comment: Thankyou! This helped me to debug for missing dependencies for quicklook plugin